# How to know which menuItem clicked when it create dynamically?

Tags: java, javafx

this is my view:

```
public class AdminPage extends VBox {
    public AdminPage() {
        Menu menu = new Menu("Optional");
        int i;
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Product");
        items.add("Profile");
        items.add("Home");

        for (i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem(items.get(i)));
        }
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        this.getChildren().addAll(menuBar);
        this.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    }
}
```

I want to write the controller but the problem is how should I know which item has clicked.

the menu is like this:

```
Optional
----------
Product
Home
```

I want if i clicked on product another form open. I think this is done with click action.

Comment: You need to do something like 

`MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(items.get(i))); 
menuItem.setOnAction(...);
menu.getItems().add(menuItem);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a handler for each menu item when you create it:

```
    for (String item : items) {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(item);
        menuItem.setOnAction(e -> {
            // do whatever you need here, e.g.
            System.out.println("You selected " + item);
        });     
        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a question, I want to write button action in my controller. Am I should create an object? Thank you for explaining this part of the code

Comment: @F.M For your additional question about action handling for buttons: If your controller is an FXML controller, see the answer to [How do I handle multiple button in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771093/how-do-i-handle-multiple-button-in-javafx/77771498#77771498). If it doesn't answer your additional question, then ask a new question as requested, with a [mcve].